# How to attached a file when composing a mail with flutter windows package url launcher?

Tags: flutter, file, flutter-windows, url-launcher

I have tried using mailer to send email but I want to first open the mail app and then ataching a file into it. So I have been using flutter windows package url launcher but I could only seem to add a subject and a body.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-path_path/toUri.html Can you try this?

Comment: @KrishBhanushali I have tried using toUri void sendMail(index) async {
  
  print(p.toUri(file[index].path));
  final Uri _emailLaunchUri = Uri(
  scheme: 'mailto',
  path: '',
  query: 'body=${p.toUri(file[index].path)}'
  
);
  launch(_emailLaunchUri.toString());
} but it doesnt seem to be attaching a file into the composing mail